# SqlServer:- Deadlock and lock issues while Inserting and viewing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-deadlocks

i have a page where i insert values into 3 tables by procedure at same point of time another user  requesting to view.  but an error of DeadLock occurs.

And also my insertation process become slow. like 50 users parallel inserting data in that tables and 15 users are requesting to view that data.

```
" DEAD LOCK victim with Process ID(52)'Error"
```

[image]

I have CusterIndex and Non ClusterIndex in all three tables. in which Page level Locking and Row Level Locking is Enabled. is it Disabling them will help me .?

[image]

it works smooth when only viewing or inserting is going on. but when simultaneous process start its hike. it fire "timeout error" or "Deadlock Victims" for Viewing. and Locks get Increasing and also the waiting time starting was 0.1< mins and later on get increase.

thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have any way to look at the deadlock graph?  If so, that will tell us what resources are involved in the deadlock and potentially how to remedy.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information than this.

Comment: For slow - start evaluating what is slow. YOu sound a little clueless (no pun intended) - can it be that the server just overloads? Many smaller setups are usig discs that make professionals laugh for database servers, then wonder why it is not fast.

Comment: As wat i found is when Locks on page level and table level get increase. when simultaneous process is been requested by users. it works smooth when only viewing or inserting is going on. but when simultaneous process start its hike. it fire "timeout error" or "Deadlock Victims" for Viewing. and Locks get Increasing and also the waiting time starting was 0.1< mins and later on get increase.